# How to automate plotting a certain set of values after simulation in OMEdit?

Tags: plot, modelica, openmodelica

I have built a fairly complex model using OMEdit. To post-process, I want to generate a set of plots (<5) with a different number of quantities (~5) plotted in each plot.

So far, I did this using the Plotting view in OMEdit. However, doing this time and time again, with the mouse, after every start of OMEdit, gets tedious very quickly, so I want to automate this.

Is there **a way to programmatically define** (e.g. with an experiment annotation) **a set of plots** belonging to a certain model, which get generated/refreshed after every simulation of said model, or at least by the click of one button or running of one script? Do I have to write a .mos script, and if yes, how do I best run that from within OMEdit?

Comment: Can you do this with the OMNotebook? I don't know it too well but a similar functionality in Mathematica/SystemModeler would let you do:
`sim=WSMSimulate["model"];
WSMPlot[sim,{"x","y"}];
WSMPlot[sim,{"y","z"},PlotStyle->Red];`
etc.

Comment: Nice, OMNotebook could work - could you provide that as an answer? I have played around a bit, and have some promising results. Sadly, one apparently can't save plots to a file using OMPlot programmatically (although it works with the save button, of course).

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard experiment annotation for it but we could have OpenModelica specific annotation to make it work.

But you don't have to select the plots every time. You only need to do it once.
- Simulate your model
- Select the plots
- Update your model
- Simulate again
- The existing plots will be automatically updated to the new values.

Comment: Yes, I know that the plots stay during one session. But, apart from the fact that the variable selection tree completely collapses with every simulation, the plots are not persistent between *sessions*, so if I close OMEdit, all the plots are lost, colours are probably incosistent (as they depend on selection order), etc.
Also, I'm also thinking of generating plots for reports, after tweaks of the model, etc, not always within one session. That's why I would like to programmatically define them - defined once, run repeatedly/easily.

Comment: For example,when I do simulations/modeling in Python (3), I write one or more functions to generate my plots and save them, when I change the model I just run that function and have how many pdfs/png + interactive plots as I need within seconds, as opposed to manually hunting for variable tickboxes again and again.

Comment: "we could have OpenModelica specific annotation to make it work" 
should I submit a ticket about that?

Comment: Yes a ticket would be fine. Perhaps with an example model explaining how you want to use it.