# OMedit : Automatically open plot with specific variable after running OMedit and simulate a model

Tags: openmodelica

Everytime I open a new windows of OMedit, and run a simulation of my model, I have to select again and again the variables I want to plot.

I would like to avoid selecting parameter each time I restart OMedit.
Something like a script that could open immediately the plots with selected parameter after the first simulation run.

DO you know if it is possible ?

There was the same question but not answer here (2016 !) :
[How to automate plotting a certain set of values after simulation in OMEdit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40283482/how-to-automate-plotting-a-certain-set-of-values-after-simulation-in-omedit)

Comment: I found this : https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/OpenModelica.Scripting.plot.html but unable to understand how to use...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not supported. See https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/issues/10181